# Horizontal Tableview for Javafx

Tags: java, javafx

Im working on a JavaFX project that has a TableView with a dynamic number or columns (ObservableList). I want to display the table horizontally so that the col titles are the begining of the row and all col values are in the row. See image below:

[image: From normal Verticle TableView to Horizontal TableView]

I've thought of rotating the whole table 90° and going into each cell individually and rotating 90° but am unsure how the TextFieldTableCell would behave doing that. Any help would be great, thanks!

```
public static void configureTable(TableView table, int cols) {
    StringUtil util = new StringUtil();
    for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
        final int j = i;
        TableColumn col = new TableColumn(util.numberToLetter(i));
        col.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
            public ObservableValue<String> call(TableColumn.CellDataFeatures<ObservableList, String> param) {
                return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().get(j).toString());
            }
        });
        col.setEditable(true);
        col.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
        col.setOnEditCommit(
                new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<ObservableList, String>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<ObservableList, String> t) {
                        String input = t.getNewValue();
                        int rowNumber = t.getTablePosition().getRow();
                        ObservableList row = t.getRowValue();
                        row.set(j, input);
                    }
                }
        );
        table.getColumns().addAll(col);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution/ workaround?