# TableView Scrolling with Large Amount of Columns is Unresponsive

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I'm transitioning some tables from Swing to FX.

I am trying to create a custom horizontal oriented `TableView` kind of like what is asked about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39619401/horizontal-tableview-for-javafx).

I utilized [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27496843/how-to-display-column-based-data-set-using-javafx-tableview) method to wrap and display my column of data. I did a bind between two table scrollbars to get a "row header". Here is what the entire thing looks like:

[image]

Then I checked how well `TableView` handled loading a large amount of data. I created a basic multiplication table with 10 columns and 100,000 rows. After the initial load-in, the table was incredibly responsive and the vertical scrollbar movement and had no issue.

My issue came when I add more columns. I believe because of the way that `TableView` expects data to be in rows instead of columns that when I add 10,000 columns and 50 rows the entire `TableView` component was unresponsive. It also took significantly longer to load-in than the 10 columns, 100k rows.

At ~4k columns and 50 rows, the table responded well to the horizontal scroll, but the vertical was very slow to respond, which is why (apart from the inherent structure) I was lead to believe TableView prefers row data to column.

Is there a way around the unresponsiveness that preferably:

- Keeps the columns as the dataset
- Doesn't involve going back to `JTables`
- Avoids pagination

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197490/javafx-tableview-issues-with-big-data) post, but it did not seem helpful and the OP went back to JTables in the end. On the other hand, this was 4 years ago and a slightly different case.

Please note I am new to posting so let me know if more info is needed.

Comment: It's a bit different and may not be right for you as it has different functionality, but perhaps, instead of a TableView, try a [ControlsFX GridView](https://controlsfx.bitbucket.io/org/controlsfx/control/GridView.html) and see if you can get the performance you need.

Comment: The example cited is a proof-of-concept; you might [profile](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2064427/230513) it to see what can be optimized for your particular use case.

Comment: @jewelsea I did start using SpreadsheetView from ControlsFX, but it seems like it instantiates a lot of the TableView in the background and GridView was not going to be powerful enough for what I had in mind. FX just seems incredibly restrictive when it comes to customization in comparison to Swing.